# I need configurable product with multiple size swatches at raleted.phtml in Magento

Tags: javascript, magento

I have created configurable product with multiple sizes(like simple products `skus-: sku-l,sku-m,sku-s,sku-xl etc.`). That is basically in Related.phtml file means I have created new template.
What I want is, when I click on size and then  on add to bag button then redirect to shopping cart.

Everything is fine but I want to fetch size with its swatches image. Can some tell where I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So I think your question is 'How can I show the swatch image of a chosen configuralbe in the shopping cart?'

The file you want to study (and copy into your theme for editing) is

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
```

You will need to work out how to get the swatch image data from the product data available here. This line of code from that default.phtml may be of interest (but you need to study your code to work out how to get the swatch file):

```
if ($_options = $this->getOptionList())
```